# XHTML Mobile 1.0 - W3C Validation Invalid because of Script

Tags: javascript, mobile, xhtml, w3c, w3c-validation

I'm trying to put Google Analytics in my Mobile web page, but seems like I'm hitting a big problem.

When trying to validate via the W3C Validator, the script tag arount the Google Analytics code is called as invalid.

> Line 10, Column 31: element "script" undefined
> `<script type="text/javascript">`
>
> You have used the element named above in your document, but the document type you are >using does not define an element of that name. This error is often caused by:
>
> incorrect use of the "Strict" document type with a document that uses frames (e.g. you must use the "Frameset" document type to get the "" element),
> by using vendor proprietary extensions such as "" or "" (this is usually fixed by using CSS to achieve the desired effect instead).
> by using upper-case tags in XHTML (in XHTML attributes and elements must be all lower-case).

I'm in XHTML Mobile 1.0, because that's a mobile Website (so I pretty much can't change from that). Is there a valid way to put in a  tag in XHTML Mobile 1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<script>` tags were added in XHTML Mobile Profile 1.1.  The latest is XHTML Mobile Profile 1.2.  I wouldn't use XHTML Mobile 1.0 unless you have a good reason.

iPhone, Android, etc. handle HTML5 just fine, by the way.

Comment: Problem is, right now my contract is to make a mobile page without HTML 5 (which W3C validator is still a little buggy...). I'll see if I can change it up for XHTML Transitional... should help me out.

Comment: If you can change to XHTML Mobile Profile 1.1 rather than 1.0, that will give you the script tag.  1.2 is the most recent.